# Android Layouts gets overlapped when using fragments and inflater to inflate the layout to fragments

Tags: android, layout, navigation-drawer, layout-inflater

I have made a Navigation Drawer Activity and want to change the layout every time a list item is selected from the navigation drawer. I have used the following code to make it work. The only problem I get is when I switch between layouts, it gets all messed up. Switching back and forth 2 layouts makes the layouts getting overlapped.

Here's my Java code to inflate the layouts.

```
        @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = null;
        switch(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)){

            case 1:
                inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_introduction, container, true);
                break;

            case 2:
                inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, true);
                break;

        }
        return rootView;
    }
```

Here's how it looks overlapped.

[image: Overlapped Layout]

Comment: set background color for fragment.

Comment: Are you using `replace` or `add` to add the fragment to activity?

Comment: I'm just inflating the layout view using inflater. Can you give me an example of how to replace the fragment layout.? Sorry I'm a bit noob. @Praveen

Comment: I mean I want see your activity code where you are adding fragement to activty using fragment transaction

Answer (score 1):

You're attaching each of those views to the container

```
@Override 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView;
    switch(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)){ 

        case 1: 
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_introduction, container, false);
            break; 

        case 2: 
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
            break; 

    }
    return rootView;
}
```

I would highly recommend finding a different solution to this.  Perhaps just create another fragment with the second view.  Maintaining this looks like it would be a disaster.